# How do I redirect stdout and stderr inside a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I would like to do in powershell the equivalent of what I do in shell:

```
exec >log 2>&1
echo stdout
badcommand-or-bad-syntax
```

i.e. I would like to catch any output the powershell will generate as the error may come from unexpected places, I do not want to do outside the powershell like:

```
my-powershell.ps1 > log 2>&1
```

because of the extra typing and also the name and location of the log is automatically determined (for example, d:<myapp>\log<servername><app>-.log).

Comment: `Start-Transcript -Path 'D:\myapp\log-servername-app-.log' -Force`, then `Stop-Transcript`?

Comment: @leeharvey1 It will serve the purpose, the problem is that it will generate special escape characters just like its Unix counterpart. The other solution I can think of is to let the program call itself with `> log 2>&1` added, and with caution that it will call end up in an endless loop.

Comment: @leeharvey1 Another issue that I found today is that the script may be accidentally terminated before reaching "Stop-Transcript".

Comment: You can put your code contents into a script block, execute it, and redirect error stream to success stream. For example, your PS1 file would contain the following: `& {  echo 'some string'; errorcommand } 2>&1`.

Comment: Then I need to put the entire script in a block, in that case, I would let the script to itself with an exit strategy.

Comment: You can have multiple script blocks. You don't need one for the whole thing. You seem to have extra requirements that you don't clearly state. What I provided does what the question in your title asks. It *appears* that you want a scoped or environmental command that will permanently redirect streams until that scope/environment is exited or overridden.

Comment: I just need what I asked: I do need to save the output of entire power shell script. Your idea is to put the entire script in a block, like this: & { entire power shell script }? It seems strange initially, but actually works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to summarize three solutions, the first two are in the comments and last one was created by me:

- Use Start-Transcript

```
$log_file = "$log_dir\$hostname-$timestamp.log"

Start-Transcript -path $log_file -append
trap {Stop-Transcript; break}
...
Stop-Transcript
```

- Use & { ... } block

```
$log_file = "$log_dir\$hostname-$timestamp.log"

& {
entire power shell script
} *> $log_file
```

- Let the script call itself with an exit strategy

```
$log_file = "$log_dir\$hostname-$timestamp.log"

"See log file: " + $log_file

if ( ($ARGS.length -eq 0) -OR ($ARGS[0] -ne "--restart") ) {
  & $PSCommandPath "--restart" @ARGS
  exit 0
}

if ($ARGS.length -eq 1) {
  $ARGS = @()
} else {
  $ARGS = $ARGS[1 .. ($ARGS.length -1)]
}
```