# Powershell trap with error in an if conditional statement

Tags: powershell

Here is my testing script:

```
trap {"trapped"}

if ($true) {
  nonsenseString1
  exit 0
}

nonsenseString2
```

and the result is:

```
trapped
nonsenseString1 : The term 'nonsenseString1' is not recognized ...
trapped
nonsenseString2 : The term 'nonsenseString2' is not recognized ...
```

If this not what I wanted and what I expected. After it trapped `nonsenseString1`, it should `exit 0`, why it doesn't? This happens in both powershell 5 and 7.

I discovered this has to do with the if conditional block. If I take off the block, then it behaves as I expected.

PS: My real purpose was to record any errors that may happen on a Powershell script, and people tell me that I should use `Start-Transcript`:

[How do I redirect stdout and stderr inside a powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68499341/how-do-i-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-inside-a-powershell-script)

Since I do not know when the error happens, I want to `Stop-Transcript` in a trap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Selectively* use a `try` / `catch` / `finally` statement** to act on a terminating error caused by an individual statement (see also the bottom section):

```
$trapActions = { "trapped" }

trap { & $trapActions }

if ($true) {
  try {
    nonsenseString1
  } catch {
    $_ | Write-Error
    & $trapActions
    exit 1
  }
}

nonsenseString2
```

<sup>Note that I'm using `exit 1`, because by convention failure is signaled with a *nonzero* exit code.</sup>

Note that `trap` only acts on *terminating* errors (both *statement* and *script*-terminating ones), not also on the more typical *non-terminating errors*.

If it's acceptable to exit on the *first* terminating error - wherever it occurs - you can simply use `trap { "trapped"; break }` in your original code.

---

As for **what you tried**:

The problem is indeed that, **when a [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) statement is triggered, the *enclosing block* (`{ ... }`) is exited**, so that the `exit 0` never executes; instead, execution resumes with the first statement *after* the block, so that `nonsenseString2` executes too.

This mirrors the behavior of the [`try { ... } catch { ... } finally { ... }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement, which was introduced later than `trap`, and is nowadays typically used in lieu of the latter.

That is, as soon as a terminating error occurs inside the `try` block, control is transferred to the `catch` block, with any remaining statements in the `try` block not getting executed.

Comment: Thank you for the enclosing block explanation! It makes sense but cannot be easily found. The problem with try and catch mechanism is that you have to set this up anywhere you suspect an issue, but the exception often happens where you least expected! Basically I want to log an error anywhere when it happens - a catch all so to speak. This can be simply achieved via "> log 2>&1" outside of the script. Inside the script, since Start-Transcript and trap "Stop-Transcript" have this strange behavior, I think I can let the script calls itself with an exit strategy. I will do that instead.

Comment: Thank you for the effort to fix the problem. I believe the original problem that leads to this problem (to catch all) can be achieved by this: `if ( $ARGS[0] -ne "--restart" ) { & $PSCommandPath "--restart" $ARGS >logfile 2>&1; exit 0; }; $ARGS = $ARGS[1,$ARGS.length]`

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, @puravidaso; note that `*> logfile` alone would capture _all_ streams; as for eliminating the first argument: you probably meant `$args = if ($args.Count -gt 1) { $args[1..($args.Count-1)] }`

Comment: I understand what you meant, it is more precise and logical to test the count, but it is too long. While $ARGS.length seems out of bound but it works in all occasions: with 0, 1, or more elements. For example, `$a=@(); $a[1,0]; ($a[1,0]).gettype()`. Am I using an undocumented bug?

Comment: @puravidaso, you want a _range_ of array elements _starting with_ the 2nd one (index `1`), that's why you need `..`, not `,` - e.g., `$args[1,3]`extracts _two individual elements_, those with index `1` and `3`. (Quick aside: `$args.Length` and `$args.Count` are equivalent). Yes, by default exceeding the upper bound of the array is quietly tolerated, but not with `Set-StrictMode -Version 3` or higher in effect (not often used). The `if` statement is necessary to guard against the single-element case, because the range expression `1..0` would then result in indices `1` and `0`.

Comment: If you're not worried about strict mode, you can therefore simplify to: `$args = $args[1..$args.Count]`, which yields the empty array if only one argument was passed.

Comment: After a second thought, the shortest code should not be the ultimate goal, but the correctness and clarity, so I adopted your method. The solution for the original problem I posted in comment has a problem: $ARGS should be expanded as $ARGS[0] $ARGS[1] $ARGS[2] ... with -join " ", or it will be considered as one argument. I summarized the solutions under the original problem under the link in the message body of this question.

Comment: @puravidaso, use `@args` instead of `$args` to pass the arguments through (using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)), which solves the problem.

Comment: This is like Unix shell's "$@" that I was looking for. Thanks!