# Call Function on all errors in Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

```
$player = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer "C:\Error-Sound.wav"
$ErrorActionPreference = "$player.Play()"
```

my code is not working
i want this when it face any error in the whole Powershell Script to call function
any help ?

Comment: You are probably looking for `$player.PlaySync()` on a `catch` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking to play a sound whenever the script fails, if that's the case then:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$player = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer "C:\Error-Sound.wav"

try
{
    # Script do something here    
}
catch
{
    $player.PlaySync() # Play a sound if Error
    Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message # Display exception in the console
}
```

Comment: This is Excellent 

Answer (score 3):

For ***script-wide* error handling**, use the **`trap` statement**, as described in the conceptual [about_Trap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) help topic.

Note that a **`trap` only traps *terminating* errors** by default, so that a non-terminating error such as `Get-ChildItem NoSuchir` would *not* be caught.

**To also trap *non-terminating* errors, set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`** (the [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) only accepts *predefined values* denoting an abstract action to perform, such as `Stop`). This promotes non-terminating to (script-)terminating errors, which `trap` then traps.

For more ***fine-grained* handling of terminating errors**, consider use of  **`try` / `catch`/ `finally`** statements, discussed in [about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69197688/45375) for examples of both.

A simple example for your use case:

```sh
trap { 
  (New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer "C:\Error-Sound.wav").PlaySync()
  # `break` causes the script to abort.
  # `continue` does too, but without issuing the error
  # Using neither continues execution.
  break 
} 

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Provoke an error
Get-ChildItem NoSuchDir
```

[Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70583934/45375) shows you an equivalent `try` / `catch` solution.

Answer (score 0):

The $[ErrorActionPreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#erroractionpreference) variable takes one of the ActionPreference enumeration values: SilentlyContinue, Stop, Continue, Inquire, Ignore, Suspend, or Break.

Post some of your code but unless your $player.play is one of the above actions then you're not using this correctly.

```
# Change the ErrorActionPreference to 'Continue'
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
# Generate a non-terminating error and continue processing the script.
Write-Error -Message  'Test Error' ; Write-Host 'Hello World'
```